# Xml string to objects using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, object, jaxb

How can I create a java object class with an xml-string using JAXB or any other way? I would like to pass the xml-string and generate a class for mapping.
I have a nested string like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <tag1>
        <tag2>
            <tag3>
                <tag4>read me</tag4>
            </tag3>
        </tag2>
    </tag1>
```

Comment: Do you have an XML schema which defines the structure of your XML document?

Comment: Nope, I'm being given a xml-string and I would like to do unmarshaling via object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your XML won't change of structure over time, you can generate a XSD file from a tool like http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html.

Here it gives me:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="tag1">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="tag2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="tag3">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tag4"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then you can store this schema on your local file system, and launch the command `xjc myFile.xsd` which will generate JAXB files for you.

More details about **xjc**, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html)